# Add trailing comma and bracket to Ruby JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, regex

I need to add commas between my hashes and encapsulate them inside square brackets. Can anyone tell me how?

Here is my code:

```
namespace :fieldfacts do
  desc "Export Topics"
  task :export_topics => :environment do
    out = []
    File.open("public/topics.json","w") do |f|
      Topic.all.each do |topic|
          api = TopicsService.new()
          topic_api = api.get(topic.topic_api_id)
          out = {
             'id' => topic.id,
             'name' => topic.name,
             'keywords_list' => topic_api.keywords_list,
             'organizations_list' => topic_api.organizations_list,
             'social_groups_list' => topic_api.social_groups_list,
             'feeds_list' => topic_api.feeds_list,
             'articles_list' => topic_api.articles_list,
             'people' => topic_api.people
          }
        f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(out))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Precision Agriculture",
  "keywords_list": null,
  "organizations_list": null,
  "social_groups_list": null,
  "feeds_list": null,
  "articles_list": null,
  "people": null
}{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Backcountry Skiing",
  "keywords_list": null,
  "organizations_list": null,
  "social_groups_list": null,
  "feeds_list": null,
  "articles_list": null,
  "people": null
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate, what you mean by "commas between hashes", some sort of array of hashes?

Comment: The output above shows 2 hashes. Hashes are encapsulated with { }. A normal json file separates each hash with a comma. @MattSanders below has provided the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are generating JSON multiple times and then appending it together, rather than generating it once.

Something like this should solve your problem (note the change in location of `f.write`):

```
namespace :fieldfacts do
  desc "Export Topics"
  task :export_topics => :environment do
    out = []
    File.open("public/topics.json","w") do |f|
      Topic.all.each do |topic|
        api = TopicsService.new()
        topic_api = api.get(topic.topic_api_id)
        out << {
           'id' => topic.id,
           'name' => topic.name,
           'keywords_list' => topic_api.keywords_list,
           'organizations_list' => topic_api.organizations_list,
           'social_groups_list' => topic_api.social_groups_list,
           'feeds_list' => topic_api.feeds_list,
           'articles_list' => topic_api.articles_list,
           'people' => topic_api.people
        }
      end
      f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(out))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you kind sir for the quick and correct solution!

Comment: Happy to help! :-)